# How does one show the default Google signin button without using a META tag?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-signin

The following article shows how to show a default Google sign in button...
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Using the following code, the signin button shows just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MYCLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer
            onload="this.onload = handleClientLoad()"
            onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

results in...

[image]

The article also mentions the CLIENT_ID can be specified in the gapi.auth2.init() method.  *I assume this means the meta tag isn't needed if the CLIENT_ID is passed in this manner?*

[image]

So with the following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        }

        function initClient() {
            // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
            var CLIENT_ID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';

            // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
            var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

            // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
            // included, separated by spaces.
            var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

            gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
                discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                scope: SCOPES
            }).then(function () {
            });
        }

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer
            onload="this.onload = handleClientLoad()"
            onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The button doesn't show.

How can I show the default Google signin button without using a meta tag with the CLIENT_ID in the header?  Also, is it a security risk to have the CLIENT_ID and API_KEY exposed in the web page?  I suppose Oauth Restrictions and API Key Restrictions mitigate the risk?

Comment: clientId is incorrect, use client_id...

`gapi.client.init({
client_id:
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the OAuth method instead. Just get an image of Google Sign in button:

[image]

and then implement the OAuth as seen in this [Calendar Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js).

Just to make sure do not expose anything on the web that's private. Maybe that sign-in sample is for testing purposes only.

As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app):

> We recommend that you design your app's auth endpoints so that your
>   application does not expose authorization codes to other resources on
>   the page.

Comment: Hello noogui, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) it says, the meta tag is used to provide information about the current web page. But why it is mandatory for a button to show up? I would like to know in detail. Can you please explain?